# Is it possible to get the number of digits mathematically?

Tags: number-theory, functions

I was wondering if it was possible to, say, have function $f$ that would return the number of digits in any given positive integer. I tried using some sort of a summation, but that failed quite miserably.

Using piecewise equations, it might be constructed something like this:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1 & \text{ if } x=1 \\2 & \text{ if } x=52 \\3 & \text{ if } x=230 \\4 & \text{ if } x=5023\\\vdots&\text{ }\vdots\end{cases}$$ This is, however, not what I want. Instead, I would like, if possible, some mathematical way of doing this.

Comment: Try $d(x)=1 + \lfloor \log_{10} x \rfloor$.

Comment: d(2) = 1.3 so I have 1.3 digits?

Comment: @MathApprentice You didn't take the floor first: $\log_{10}(2)\approx .3$.  So, you take the floor of that and get $0$.  So, $d(2)=1+0=1$.

Comment: You may be interested in my answer to this related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795412/no-of-digit-in-xy-where-x-y-in-mathbbn/795473#795473

Comment: @MPW Thanks, very interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x) = 1+\lfloor \log_{10}(x)\rfloor$$
More generally,
$$f(x) = 1+\lfloor \log_{b}(x)\rfloor$$ returns the number of digits of the number in base $b$.

Comment: so, $1 + log_{10} (2) = 1.3$ so I have 1.3 digits?

Comment: $f(x) = 1+\lfloor \log_{b}(x)\rfloor$, $f(n)=-1$, if $0<n<.1$

Comment: @MathApprentice Don't you see the floor function?

Comment: Oh that's what the half-brackets mean. Okay.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* The integer part of the logarithm in base 10 is the function you look for.

Comment: Not quite. It's one more than that.

Comment: Of course, I was pointing out which function the OP would want to use to find the solution. Notice the difference between "the solution is" and "you need to look for".

Comment: I accept that. But it isn't at all clear in your answer. OP specifically asks for a function that gives the answer he seeks, and you stated that your function is the one he is looking for. If you are suggesting a gentle hint instead of an explicit answer (which I encourage, incidentally), it's usually an excellent idea to preface your answer with the disclaimer "**Hint:**" to make that clear. I can't withdraw my downvote unless you edit your answer because the site won't let me.

Comment: @MPW edited. :)